# python: os.spawn . cannot start bash process on background

Tags: python, bash

Task is to execute bash script from python script and let it execute on background, even if python script will finish. I need UNIX solution and i do not care if it will be not working on Win.

Python script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, commands
command = '/usr/bin/ssh localhost "/home/gd/test/python/back.sh  "   '
print os.spawnlp(os.P_NOWAIT,command)
print "Python done"
```

/home/gd/test/python/back.sh  :

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

/bin/echo "started"
/bin/sleep 80
/bin/echo "ended"
```

The issue is, when python script starts , i see PID of spawned process printed. But there is no process on background. When i use P_WAIT  i see exit code 127 which means that command not found in the path. But i already provided all paths that already possible?
These scripts works perfectly with commands.getouput.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
command = ['/usr/bin/ssh', 'ssh', 'localhost', '/home/gd/test/python/back.sh']
print os.spawnlp(os.P_NOWAIT, *command)
print "Python done"
```

Note that it's preferable to use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-the-os-spawn-family) module here instead of spawn

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import Popen
command = ['/usr/bin/ssh', 'localhost', '/home/gd/test/python/back.sh']
print Popen(command)
print "Python done"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot gnibbler. i have two questions : 1. Will spawn* or popen combine all commands provide to a single one? because it could be executed as "ssh; localhost; back.sh;" instead of "ssh localhost back.sh". 2. Will Popen spawn process that will be independable from parent? I.e.  if parent will finish , will child continue to run until its logical end?

Comment: Tested both. Spawnlp not working as expected. It executes "ssh; localhost; back.sh" . Therefore it fails with localhost - command not found. Popen works as gnibbler told.

Comment: @Daniel, make sure you didn't miss the extra 'ssh' in the spawn command

Comment: ah.. indeed. now both works! But i still cannot figure out , why there are duplicate ssh at the beginning. Manual says that first in brackets is treated as "mode" , but it did not explain what does this module means?

Comment: also , how can i supress ssh banner ? I`ve already tried to put 2>/dev/null to the end of typle, but  this do not work. I`m still confused how spawn or popen compile this tuple in one command.

Comment: Finally , i found solution to my problems :command = 'ssh localhost /home/gd/test/python/back.sh 2>/dev/null' 
print Popen(command,shell=True) . This will supress banner.